# Grok regex with escaped “[“, “(“, and “)” chars problems

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Elastic newbie here - working with a new 5.5 install. I have a log line that looks like so:

> [2015/10/01@19:48:22.785-0400] P-4780 T-2208 I DBUTIL : (451) prostrct
>   create session begin for timk519 on CON:.

I have the following regex:

```
\[%{DATE:date}@%{TIME:time}-(?<gmtoffset>\d{4})\]\s*(?<procid>P-[0-9]+)\s*(?<threadid>T-[0-9]+)\s*(?<msgtype>[ifIF])\s*(?<processtype>[a-zA-Z]+)\s*(?<usernumber>[0-9]+|[:])\s*\((?<msgnum>[0-9]+|[\-]+)\)\s*%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

When I try it in the kibana grok debugger it doesn't work and I get the following error:

> GrokDebugger: [parse_exception] [pattern_definitions] property isn't a
>   map, but of type [java.lang.String], with { header={
>   processor_type="grok" & property_name="pattern_definitions" } }

this appears to be due to the \[ at the start of the line. If I replace the leading \[ with a period "." I get this

```
.%{DATE:date}@%{TIME:time}-(?<gmtoffset>\d{4})\]\s*(?<procid>P-[0-9]+)\s*(?<threadid>T-[0-9]+)\s*(?<msgtype>[ifIF])\s*(?<processtype>[a-zA-Z]+)\s*(?<usernumber>[0-9]+|[:])\s*\((?<msgnum>[0-9]+|[\-]+)\)\s*%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

the grok debugger and https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ are good with this pattern.

When I put this regex into logstash, it fails to recognize the msgnum *(451)* part of the line because of the escaped parens \( and \) around the msgnum field, and as a result fails to recognize the line as a legal string.

Am I escaping something incorrectly? Is this a bug?

**UPDATE 2017-07-21**

I got around the issue with escaping ( and ) by putting them in [(] and [)]. I haven't figured out a way to solve matching the leading [ yet.

**UPDATE 2017-07-24**

The answer below was an epic catch and I've used that to create the following custom patterns:

```
DBTIME %{TIME}[-+]\d{4}
DBTIMESTAMP %{YEAR}/%{MONTHNUM}/%{MONTHDAY}@%{DBTIME}
```

which I've implemented in my grok statement like so:

```
\[%{DBTIMESTAMP:dbdatetime}\]\s*%{PROCESSID:processid}\s*%{DBTHREADID:threadid}\s*%{DBMSGTYPE:msgtype}\s*%{PROCESSTYPE:processtype}?\s*%{USERNUMBER:usernumber}?\s*:\s*[(]%{MSGNUMBER:msgnumber}[)].\s*%{GREEDYDATA:eventmessage}\s*\r
```

I then use the date filter to turn the dbdatetime into a @timestamp setting, and now the regex matches the incoming log stream which is what I want. Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The devil is in the detail and the error is not apparent at first. The reason the Grok Debugger fails is because of your use of the `DATE` pattern. This pattern resolves like this:

```
DATE_US %{MONTHNUM}[/-]%{MONTHDAY}[/-]%{YEAR}
DATE_EU %{MONTHDAY}[./-]%{MONTHNUM}[./-]%{YEAR}
```

`MONTHNUM` and `MONTHDAY` are both 2 digit patterns, which in turn actually means they are matching the 15 in your year. This is the reason why the pattern does not work because `\[%{DATE}` is actually not matching (it is missing the 20). Why does the pattern `.%{DATE}` work tough? Because you are not matching the `[` with the dot, your are matching the `0` of the year.

How to fix this? Use a custom pattern to match the date. Something like this works:

```
\[(?<date>%{YEAR}/%{MONTHNUM}/%{MONTHDAY})@%{TIME:time}-(?<gmtoffset>\d{4})\]\s*(?<procid>P-[0-9]+)\s*(?<threadid>T-[0-9]+)\s*(?<msgtype>[ifIF])\s*(?<processtype>[a-zA-Z]+)\s*(?<usernumber>[0-9]+|[:])\s*\((?<msgnum>[0-9]+|[\-]+)\)\s*%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

This will return the following output:

```
{
  "date": "2015/10/01",
  "msgnum": "451",
  "procid": "P-4780",
  "processtype": "DBUTIL",
  "message": "prostrct create session begin for timk519 on CON:.",
  "threadid": "T-2208",
  "usernumber": ":",
  "gmtoffset": "0400",
  "time": "19:48:22.785",
  "msgtype": "I"
}
```

Comment: Absolutely epic catch!